# How do use HTTP for FTP server in Bash?

Tags: bash, http, ftp

Other than FTP command, is it possible to use HTTP to DOWNLOAD, UPLOAD, Delete or list the file from FTPServer?

Comment: try `wget` or `curl` they are tools of interest for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download:

```
wget <the url>
```

Upload:

```
curl -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost" url.com
wget --header="Content-type: multipart/form-data boundary=FILEUPLOAD" --post-file postfile <url with uploadform>
```

Since you have posted a generic question so please take it as generic answer.